# Oracle ratio_to_report in hive

Tags: hive

Is there a same function available in Hive?

ratio_to_report in oracle

```
SELECT last_name, salary, RATIO_TO_REPORT(salary) OVER () AS rr
   FROM employees
   WHERE job_id = 'PU_CLERK';

LAST_NAME                     SALARY         RR
------------------------- ---------- ----------
Khoo                            3100 .223021583
Baida                           2900 .208633094
Tobias                          2800 .201438849
Himuro                          2600  .18705036
Colmenares                      2500 .179856115
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function in Hive. However, you can make use of the available analytical functions to do the same thing.

```
SELECT last_name, salary, salary/SUM(salary) OVER () AS rr 
FROM employees
WHERE job_id = 'PU_CLERK'
```

To get the ratio per `job_id`, use

```
SELECT last_name, salary, salary/SUM(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY job_id) AS rr 
FROM employees
```

Comment: Exactly the same thing i did. Thanks !